# Dealing with repeated retaggers during reviews

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, review

I've just been bouncing around the review queue, and there have been a couple of users who have been repeatedly adding semi-relevant/completely irrelevant tags to questions. Most of the time they get rejected as 'too minor' but the sheer volume of them means some are getting through due to people just hitting 'accept'. Seems to be a way to get easy reputation.

Is there a sensible way of saying "not only is this edit invalid, but the user needs to be scrutinized" while performing reviews? If not, I'd like to suggest such a feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already such a feature, if too many edits are rejected a user is automatically blocked from suggesting more edits for a week.